# ArangoDB: Optimize query for ingestion of interconnected data in a graph

Tags: query-optimization, arangodb

I am trying to create a query to create a graph that contains packages (in the form of a trie) that contain a root level "pkg", its type, namespace, name, and finally version (which also contains subpath and qualifier list). I want to connect two different "packages" with a new node in between called "isDependency" and then create the corresponding edges between the 3 nodes (2 package nodes and 1 isDependency node).

The current query I have is:

```
LET firstPkg = FIRST(
        FOR pkg IN Pkg
        FILTER pkg.root == "pkg"
        FOR pkgHasType IN OUTBOUND pkg PkgHasType
            FILTER pkgHasType.type == @pkgType
          FOR pkgHasNamespace IN OUTBOUND pkgHasType PkgHasNamespace
                  FILTER pkgHasNamespace.namespace == @namespace
              FOR pkgHasName IN OUTBOUND pkgHasNamespace PkgHasName
                      FILTER pkgHasName.name == @name
                FOR pkgHasVersion IN OUTBOUND pkgHasName PkgHasVersion
                          FILTER pkgHasVersion.version == @version && pkgHasVersion.subpath == @subpath && pkgHasVersion.qualifier_list == @qualifier
                  RETURN {
                    "type": pkgHasType.type,
                    "namespace": pkgHasNamespace.namespace,
                    "name": pkgHasName.name,
                    "version": pkgHasVersion.version,
                    "subpath": pkgHasVersion.subpath,
                    "qualifier_list": pkgHasVersion.qualifier_list,
                    "versionDoc": pkgHasVersion
                  }
      )
      
      LET secondPkg = FIRST(
        FOR pkg IN Pkg
          FILTER pkg.root == "pkg"
          FOR pkgHasType IN OUTBOUND pkg PkgHasType
              FILTER pkgHasType.type == @secondPkgType
            FOR pkgHasNamespace IN OUTBOUND pkgHasType PkgHasNamespace
                FILTER pkgHasNamespace.namespace == @secondNamespace
              FOR pkgHasName IN OUTBOUND pkgHasNamespace PkgHasName
                      FILTER pkgHasName.name == @secondName
                  RETURN {
                    "type": pkgHasType.type,
                    "namespace": pkgHasNamespace.namespace,
                    "name": pkgHasName.name,
                    "nameDoc": pkgHasName
                  }
      )
      
      LET isDependency = FIRST(
          UPSERT { packageID:firstPkg.versionDoc._id, depPackageID:secondPkg.nameDoc._id, versionRange:@versionRange, dependencyType:@dependencyType, justification:@justification, collector:@collector, origin:@origin } 
              INSERT { packageID:firstPkg.versionDoc._id, depPackageID:secondPkg.nameDoc._id, versionRange:@versionRange, dependencyType:@dependencyType, justification:@justification, collector:@collector, origin:@origin } 
              UPDATE {} IN isDependencies
              RETURN NEW
      )
      
      LET edgeCollection = (FOR edgeData IN [
        {fromKey: isDependency._key, toKey: secondPkg.nameDoc._key, from: isDependency._id, to: secondPkg.nameDoc._id, label: "dependency"}, 
        {fromKey: firstPkg.versionDoc._key, toKey: isDependency._key, from: firstPkg.versionDoc._id, to: isDependency._id, label: "subject"}]
    
        INSERT { _key: CONCAT("isDependencyEdges", edgeData.fromKey, edgeData.toKey), _from: edgeData.from, _to: edgeData.to, label : edgeData.label } INTO isDependencyEdges OPTIONS { overwriteMode: "ignore" }
      )
      
      RETURN {
          "firstPkgType": firstPkg.type,
          "firstPkgNamespace": firstPkg.namespace,
          "firstPkgName": firstPkg.name,
          "firstPkgVersion": firstPkg.version,
          "firstPkgSubpath": firstPkg.subpath,
          "firstPkgQualifier_list": firstPkg.qualifier_list,
          "secondPkgType": secondPkg.type,
          "secondPkgNamespace": secondPkg.namespace,
          "secondPkgName": secondPkg.name,
          "versionRange": isDependency.versionRange,
          "dependencyType": isDependency.dependencyType,
          "justification": isDependency.justification,
          "collector": isDependency.collector,
          "origin": isDependency.origin
      }
```

I have also created a bunch of indexes to help improve the lookup:

Utilizing the arangoDB Go driver, I have created the following indexes.

```
if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "PkgType", []string{"type"}, true, "byType"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for PkgType: %w", err)
        }

        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "PkgHasType", []string{"_from", "_to"}, true, "byFromTo"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for PkgHasType: %w", err)
        }

        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "PkgNamespace", []string{"namespace"}, false, "byNamespace"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for PkgNamespace: %w", err)
        }
        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "PkgHasNamespace", []string{"_from", "_to"}, true, "byFromTo"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for PkgHasNamespace: %w", err)
        }

        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "PkgName", []string{"name"}, false, "byName"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for PkgName: %w", err)
        }

        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "PkgHasName", []string{"_from", "_to"}, true, "byFromTo"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for PkgHasName: %w", err)
        }

        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "PkgVersion", []string{"version"}, false, "byVersion"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for PkgVersion: %w", err)
        }

        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "PkgVersion", []string{"subpath"}, false, "bySubpath"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for PkgVersion: %w", err)
        }

        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "PkgVersion", []string{"qualifier_list[*]"}, false, "byQualifierList"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for PkgVersion: %w", err)
        }

        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "PkgVersion", []string{"version", "subpath", "qualifier_list[*]"}, false, "byAllVersion"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for PkgVersion: %w", err)
        }

        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "PkgHasVersion", []string{"_from", "_to"}, true, "byFromTo"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for PkgHasVersion: %w", err)
        }

        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "isDependencies", []string{"packageID", "depPackageID", "origin"}, true, "byPkgIDDepPkgIDOrigin"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for isDependencies: %w", err)
        }

        if err := createIndexPerCollection(ctx, db, "isDependencyEdges", []string{"_from", "_to"}, true, "byFromTo"); err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("failed to generate index for isDependencyEdges: %w", err)
        }
```

The query seems to get slower and slower as I ingest more and more data, is there any performance improvement I can make on the query or even the structure of how the data is stored in the database?

I have tried creating indexes and removing as many upserts with inserts as possible. It seems to work fine initially, but the query is very slow after more data is added.

Here is the explain from the arangoDB UI:

```
Query String (2983 chars, cacheable: false):
 LET firstPkg = FIRST(
        FOR pkg IN Pkg
        FILTER pkg.root == "pkg"
        FOR pkgHasType IN OUTBOUND pkg PkgHasType
                FILTER pkgHasType.type == @pkgType
          FOR pkgHasNamespace IN OUTBOUND pkgHasType PkgHasNamespace
                  FILTER pkgHasNamespace.namespace == @namespace
              FOR pkgHasName IN OUTBOUND pkgHasNamespace PkgHasName
                      FILTER pkgHasName.name == @name
                FOR pkgHasVersion IN OUTBOUND pkgHasName PkgHasVersion
                          FILTER pkgHasVersion.version == @version
                  RETURN {
                    "type": pkgHasType.type,
                    "namespace": pkgHasNamespace.namespace,
                    "name": pkgHasName.name,
                    "version": pkgHasVersion.version,
                    "subpath": pkgHasVersion.subpath,
                    "qualifier_list": pkgHasVersion.qualifier_list,
                    "versionDoc": pkgHasVersion
                  }
      )
      
      LET secondPkg = FIRST(
        FOR pkg IN Pkg
          FILTER pkg.root == "pkg"
          FOR pkgHasType IN OUTBOUND pkg PkgHasType
              FILTER pkgHasType.type == @secondPkgType
            FOR pkgHasNamespace IN OUTBOUND pkgHasType PkgHasNamesp...

Execution plan:
 Id   NodeType                  Est.   Comment
  1   SingletonNode                1   * ROOT
 74   SubqueryStartNode            1     - LET #12 = ( /* subquery begin */
 23   EnumerateCollectionNode      1       - FOR pkg IN Pkg   /* full collection scan (projections: `_id`, `root`)  */   FILTER (pkg.`root` == "pkg")   /* early pruning */
 26   TraversalNode                7         - FOR pkgHasType  /* vertex (projections: `_id`, `type`) */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND pkg /* startnode */  PkgHasType
 29   TraversalNode               19           - FOR pkgHasNamespace  /* vertex (projections: `_id`, `namespace`) */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND pkgHasType /* startnode */  PkgHasNamespace
 32   TraversalNode               40             - FOR pkgHasName  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND pkgHasNamespace /* startnode */  PkgHasName
 63   LimitNode                    1               - LIMIT 0, 1
 35   CalculationNode              1               - LET #63 = { "type" : pkgHasType.`type`, "namespace" : pkgHasNamespace.`namespace`, "name" : pkgHasName.`name`, "nameDoc" : pkgHasName }   /* simple expression */
 75   SubqueryEndNode              1               - RETURN  #63 ) /* subquery end */
 72   SubqueryStartNode            1     - LET #5 = ( /* subquery begin */
  3   EnumerateCollectionNode      1       - FOR pkg IN Pkg   /* full collection scan (projections: `_id`, `root`)  */   FILTER (pkg.`root` == "pkg")   /* early pruning */
  6   TraversalNode                7         - FOR pkgHasType  /* vertex (projections: `_id`, `type`) */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND pkg /* startnode */  PkgHasType
  9   TraversalNode               19           - FOR pkgHasNamespace  /* vertex (projections: `_id`, `namespace`) */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND pkgHasType /* startnode */  PkgHasNamespace
 12   TraversalNode               40             - FOR pkgHasName  /* vertex (projections: `_id`, `name`) */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND pkgHasNamespace /* startnode */  PkgHasName
 15   TraversalNode                1               - FOR pkgHasVersion  /* vertex */ IN 1..1  /* min..maxPathDepth */ OUTBOUND pkgHasName /* startnode */  PkgHasVersion
 62   LimitNode                    1                 - LIMIT 0, 1
 18   CalculationNode              1                 - LET #47 = { "type" : pkgHasType.`type`, "namespace" : pkgHasNamespace.`namespace`, "name" : pkgHasName.`name`, "version" : pkgHasVersion.`version`, "subpath" : pkgHasVersion.`subpath`, "qualifier_list" : pkgHasVersion.`qualifier_list`, "versionDoc" : pkgHasVersion }   /* simple expression */
 73   SubqueryEndNode              1                 - RETURN  #47 ) /* subquery end */
 49   CalculationNode              1     - LET #69 = {  }   /* json expression */   /* const assignment */
 21   CalculationNode              1     - LET firstPkg = FIRST(#5)   /* simple expression */
 38   CalculationNode              1     - LET secondPkg = FIRST(#12)   /* simple expression */
 48   CalculationNode              1     - LET #67 = { "packageID" : firstPkg.`versionDoc`.`_id`, "depPackageID" : secondPkg.`nameDoc`.`_id`, "versionRange" : "1.0-SNAPSHOT-all", "dependencyType" : "Direct", "justification" : "test", "collector" : "test", "origin" : "test" }   /* simple expression */
 68   SubqueryStartNode            1     - LET #21 = ( /* subquery begin */
 70   SubqueryStartNode            1       - LET #18 = ( /* subquery begin */
 64   IndexNode                    1         - FOR #16 IN isDependencies   /* persistent index scan, index scan + document lookup; read own writes */    FILTER ((((((#16.`packageID` == firstPkg.`versionDoc`.`_id`) && (#16.`depPackageID` == secondPkg.`nameDoc`.`_id`)) && (#16.`versionRange` == "1.0-SNAPSHOT-all")) && (#16.`dependencyType` == "Direct")) && (#16.`justification` == "test")) && (#16.`collector` == "test"))   /* early pruning */   
 44   LimitNode                    1           - LIMIT 0, 1
 71   SubqueryEndNode              1           - RETURN  #16 ) /* subquery end */
 47   CalculationNode              1       - LET $OLD = #18[0]   /* simple expression */
 50   UpsertNode                   1       - UPSERT $OLD INSERT #67 UPDATE #69 IN isDependencies
 69   SubqueryEndNode              1       - RETURN  $NEW ) /* subquery end */
 53   CalculationNode              1     - LET isDependency = FIRST(#21)   /* simple expression */
 55   CalculationNode              1     - LET #71 = [ { "fromKey" : isDependency.`_key`, "toKey" : secondPkg.`nameDoc`.`_key`, "from" : isDependency.`_id`, "to" : secondPkg.`nameDoc`.`_id`, "label" : "dependency" }, { "fromKey" : firstPkg.`versionDoc`.`_key`, "toKey" : isDependency.`_key`, "from" : firstPkg.`versionDoc`.`_id`, "to" : isDependency.`_id`, "label" : "subject" } ]   /* simple expression */
 66   SubqueryStartNode            1     - LET edgeCollection = ( /* subquery begin */
 56   EnumerateListNode            2       - FOR edgeData IN #71   /* list iteration */
 57   CalculationNode              2         - LET #73 = { "_key" : CONCAT("isDependencyEdges", edgeData.`fromKey`, edgeData.`toKey`), "_from" : edgeData.`from`, "_to" : edgeData.`to`, "label" : edgeData.`label` }   /* simple expression */
 58   InsertNode                   0         - INSERT #73 IN isDependencyEdges 
 67   SubqueryEndNode              1       - ) /* subquery end */
 60   CalculationNode              1     - LET #75 = { "firstPkgType" : firstPkg.`type`, "firstPkgNamespace" : firstPkg.`namespace`, "firstPkgName" : firstPkg.`name`, "firstPkgVersion" : firstPkg.`version`, "firstPkgSubpath" : firstPkg.`subpath`, "firstPkgQualifier_list" : firstPkg.`qualifier_list`, "secondPkgType" : secondPkg.`type`, "secondPkgNamespace" : secondPkg.`namespace`, "secondPkgName" : secondPkg.`name`, "versionRange" : isDependency.`versionRange`, "dependencyType" : isDependency.`dependencyType`, "justification" : isDependency.`justification`, "collector" : isDependency.`collector`, "origin" : isDependency.`origin` }   /* simple expression */
 61   ReturnNode                   1     - RETURN #75

Indexes used:
 By   Name                    Type         Collection        Unique   Sparse   Cache   Selectivity   Fields                                      Stored values   Ranges
 26   edge                    edge         PkgHasType        false    false    false       14.29 %   [ `_from` ]                                 [  ]            base OUTBOUND
 29   edge                    edge         PkgHasNamespace   false    false    false        5.17 %   [ `_from` ]                                 [  ]            base OUTBOUND
 32   edge                    edge         PkgHasName        false    false    false        2.45 %   [ `_from` ]                                 [  ]            base OUTBOUND
  6   edge                    edge         PkgHasType        false    false    false       14.29 %   [ `_from` ]                                 [  ]            base OUTBOUND
  9   edge                    edge         PkgHasNamespace   false    false    false        5.17 %   [ `_from` ]                                 [  ]            base OUTBOUND
 12   edge                    edge         PkgHasName        false    false    false        2.45 %   [ `_from` ]                                 [  ]            base OUTBOUND
 15   edge                    edge         PkgHasVersion     false    false    false       78.06 %   [ `_from` ]                                 [  ]            base OUTBOUND
 64   byPkgIDDepPkgIDOrigin   persistent   isDependencies    true     false    true       100.00 %   [ `packageID`, `depPackageID`, `origin` ]   [  ]            ((#16.`packageID` == FIRST(#5).`versionDoc`.`_id`) && (#16.`depPackageID` == FIRST(#12).`nameDoc`.`_id`) && (#16.`origin` == "test"))
 50   primary                 primary      isDependencies    true     false    false      100.00 %   [ `_key` ]                                  [  ]            $OLD

Functions used:
 Name     Deterministic   Cacheable   Uses V8
 FIRST    true            true        false  
 CONCAT   true            true        false  

Traversals on graphs:
 Id  Depth  Vertex collections  Edge collections  Options                                  Filter / Prune Conditions                               
 26  1..1                       PkgHasType        uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path  FILTER (pkgHasType.`type` == "maven")                   
 29  1..1                       PkgHasNamespace   uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path  FILTER (pkgHasNamespace.`namespace` == "org.vulhub.App")
 32  1..1                       PkgHasName        uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path  FILTER (pkgHasName.`name` == "log4jrce")                
 6   1..1                       PkgHasType        uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path  FILTER (pkgHasType.`type` == "maven")                   
 9   1..1                       PkgHasNamespace   uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path  FILTER (pkgHasNamespace.`namespace` == "rt")            
 12  1..1                       PkgHasName        uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path  FILTER (pkgHasName.`name` == "rt")                      
 15  1..1                       PkgHasVersion     uniqueVertices: none, uniqueEdges: path  FILTER (pkgHasVersion.`version` == "1.8.0_342")         

Optimization rules applied:
 Id   RuleName
  1   move-calculations-up
  2   move-filters-up
  3   optimize-subqueries
  4   move-calculations-up-2
  5   move-filters-up-2
  6   remove-data-modification-out-variables
  7   use-indexes
  8   remove-filter-covered-by-index
  9   optimize-traversals
 10   remove-filter-covered-by-traversal
 11   remove-unnecessary-calculations-2
 12   move-calculations-down
 13   move-filters-into-enumerate
 14   reduce-extraction-to-projection
 15   splice-subqueries

45 rule(s) executed, 1 plan(s) created, peak mem [b]: 98304, exec time [s]: 0.00201

Write query options:
 Option                   Value
 waitForSync              false
 skipDocumentValidation   false
 keepNull                 true
 mergeObjects             true
 ignoreRevs               true
 isRestore                false
 overwriteMode            "ignore"
 ignoreErrors             false
 ignoreDocumentNotFound   false
 consultAqlWriteFilter    false
 exclusive                false
```

Comment: I haven't used ArangoDB yet, but typically the first step in optimizing query performance is to get an understanding of what is causing the current slowness. The standard technique for doing so is by gathering the explain plan(s) for the query, which [ArangoDB seems to support](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/execution-and-performance-explaining-queries.html). I'd recommend gathering that information and adding it to the question for additional context. Looks additional docs on the topic are [here](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/execution-and-performance-optimizer.html)

Comment: Added the explain plan to the question above! I have looked into the optimization documentation on the arango site.